# Populating a dropdown list based on the selection from another

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to populate a drop down list that contains city names based on what country the user selects.
This is the country's drop down list:

```
<select name = "country" onChange = "loadcities(this.value)">
        <?php
            include 'dbconnect.php';
            $query = "SELECT * FROM Country";
            $result = $mysqli->query($query);
            while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
                echo "<option value = '$row[0]'> $row[2] </option>";
            }
        ?>
    </select>
```

I am using this javascript function to populate it:

```
function loadcities(selected){
var s = document.getElementById("city");
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
            var citynames = (xmlhttp.response).slice();
            for(var i = 0; i < citynames.length(); i++){
                var option = document.createElement(i.toString());
                option.text = citynames[i];
                s.add(option);
            }
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "loadcities.php?q=" + str, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
```

}

and this is the php file that is used inside the previous function:

```
<?php
$q = $_REQUEST["q"];
include "dbconnect.php";
$citynames = []; 
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT cityname from CITY WHERE City.countryid = '$q'");
while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
    $cityname[] = $row[2];
}
echo "$citynames";
?>
```

I realize there are probably a lot of mistakes, but I have no idea how to fix them. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: (1) if your `$q` is a string, strings in queries need to be quoted - `... WHERE City.countryid = '$q'`. (2) You should sanitize your data, and since you are using `mysqli` use a prepared statement

Comment: @Sean Do I need to sanitize even when the user is only picking from a drop down list and not inputting anything manually.

Comment: in php you can't just echo an array `echo "$citynames";`. you could try `echo implode($citynames)`. Also, your `slice()` in `var citynames = (xmlhttp.response).slice();` should probably be `split()`, and since php `implode()` returns a comma separated string, you could do `var citynames = (xmlhttp.response).split(',');`

Comment: yes, always sanitize. right now you can directly inject by going to `loadcities.php?q=injected_code`

Answer (score 0):

First of all in the 3rd code segment you have both $cityname and $citynames. I think they should be the same. Also you are fetching one column from the data base and then using the **THIRD** column ($row[**2**]). Probably this should be $row[0].

in the end you are echo-ing an array... that will simply output `array` and not the array's contents. Also in the 2nd part, in the javascript code, you are using slice() which is used to get a set of values from an array into a new array.

I believe that you should change your 3rd code fragment to:

```
<?php
$q = $_REQUEST["q"];
include "dbconnect.php";
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT cityname from CITY WHERE City.countryid = $q");
while($row = $result->fetch_array())
{
    echo $row[0].'@@@@';
}
?>
```

Then you should change your in your javascript the line that is:

```
var citynames = (xmlhttp.response).slice();
```

to

```
var citynames = (xmlhttp.response).split('@@@@');
```

As a side note your PHP script has a huge security vulnerability: you are passing $_REQUEST input directly to the database. You should sanitize it before doing so, or you run the risk to get hacked.

Comment: Im fetching one row and using the third column in that row. That's why I wrote $row[2]. I'm aware of the security problem, but it's a small uni project with a very short deadline and the teacher told us not to take security into consideration for now.

Comment: No you are not getting a row. You select a column from a row. To get the row you would need to `select * from ... `
Did you try the the changes ? Did they work for you ?

Comment: I rewrote the code entirely and fixed up all the errors.